# How to remove duplicates rows out of table where certian field is equal to specified

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, excel

Hi I have a Matching Application that matches two fields using Jaro algorythms.

How can I remove the following : Please see the image link below to understand my question :)

[image: http://www2.picturepush.com/photo/a/13121095/640/13121095.jpg]

Thanks

Comment: Is it "keep row with highest match for str1" or "keep row where str1 = str2", or "keep row where str1 = str2, per str1" or some other combination? It is ambiguous currently

Comment: On second thoughts, does match descrive the str1-str2 correlation? If so, it is "keep row with highest match for str1". What is there are 2 matches with 100% for a given str1?

Comment: Hi there, nope. I always have two lists of names to compare and each word from list one compares to every word in list 2. Then i get matches, but as you can see in my uploaded picture, The first one was already a 100% match, so it is unnecessary for that same str1 that has been matched 100% to repeat on other matches... Don't hesitate to ask further questions, it is quite a complicated question. I have to go through the matches myself each time to make sure because there is always misspelled words and if i miss something it can have big complications

Comment: my answer should do it then

Comment: So basically, All I want to do is, If str1 have matched 100%, delete all the other rows where str1 is equal to the one that matched 100%. Some times I get str1 that matches 100% to str2 and then i getsame str1 that matches another 100 str2's but if i allready had a 100% match for it, i don't care about the rest.

Comment: I'm testing it now thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "keep row with highest match for str1" then this

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (str1 varchar(50), str2 varchar(50), MATCH decimal (5,2));
INSERT @t VALUES 
        ('ABC ELEC', 'ABC ELEC', 100),  ('ABC ELEC', 'ABB ELEC', 95), 
        ('ABC ELEC', 'ABC ELEK', 92.5), ('ABC ELEC', 'ABF ELEC', 91.5), 
        ('ABC ELEC', 'ADD ELEK', 95.5), ('BBC INVEST', 'BBC DOMEST ELEC', 85.94);

DELETE X
FROM
    (
    SELECT
       str1, str2,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.str1 ORDER BY T.MATCH DESC) AS rn
    FROM
        @t T
    ) X
WHERE rn > 1;

SELECT * FROM @t T;
```